# Basket items optimisation minimising constraints

Tags: bigdata, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I have a real problem (not home work) when I have to distribute an ordered list by position to respect some constraints

eg.

```
1. 11
2. 15
3. 18
4. 18
5. 1
```

baskets:

```
b1: 11, 1
b2: 18,15, 18
```

to respect as much as possible

```
b1 = 30%
b2 = 70%
```

I do not want to use a brute force since I'm working with long list (>10.000 items).

Can you propose a technique or a library?